# The issue of Validating certificate from MIT CSAIL's svn

Tags: ros, kinect, svn, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I am very new to ROS and I am using the mit-ros-pkg and installing Kinect Demos for Electric (my ubuntu version 11.04 and ros Electric). There is one step to Validate certificate from MIT CSAIL's svn. When I run the code "svn list https://svn.csail.mit.edu". It says "svn: Repository moved temporarily to ‘https://svn.csail.mit.edu:1443/admin/admin.cgi’; Please relocate." Does that matter? Or I can just ignore it? I have tried to run the code " svn list [https://svn.csail.mit.edu:1443/admin/admin.cgi"](https://svn.csail.mit.edu:1443/admin/admin.cgi%22) and then it said " Certification in the field:[https://svn.csail.mit.edu:1443"](https://svn.csail.mit.edu:1443%22) and asked to input the "Client certificate file name". I don't know what to do. Help! Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34496/the-issue-of-validating-certificate-from-mit-csail%27s-svn/) by [tan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2317/tan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't seem to be having any trouble with it.  I think that you need to have the actual repository name on the end of the address there.

```
∫ svn list https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/
backup_files/
branches/
install_scripts/
mit-ros-pkg.rosinstall
reinstalling_nvidia.txt
tags/
trunk/
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1